# Is it possible to choose line ending character for display purposes?

Tags: notepad++, line-endings

With PDF files some of the data is text and some of the data is raw data streams.

In writing a parser for PDF files I am using NotePad++ to look at the file to see the individual characters and also using [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) to view the hex codes.

When a PDF file is open with NotePad++ it considers either a **CR** (0xOD 13) or **LF** (0x0A 10) to be a line end character and uses either character to display the start of a new line. However I need only **LF** to be considered a new line character and start an new line for display purposes and **CR** to not be considered a new line character.

While editing there is a way to change the EOL characters entered when the return key is pressed, (Menu: Edit -> EOL Conversion)  I can find no way to change the way the line end characters are used to format the display.

Also there is a language option for PostScript which if you know PDF is the basis of PDF; that also does not format the lines as desired.

Is it possible in NotePad++ to state that **LF** is to start a new line for display purposes and that **CR** is to be considered just another value for display?

Here is a example that shows NotePad++ formatting the text with both **CR** and **LF** as EOL which is not what is needed.

[image]

This should be only 4 lines displayed.

Line 2 is split at **CR** which is not desired.

[image]

---

EDIT

Based on comment by [Julio](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7500028/julio).

While I would not consider this an acceptable answer, it is a good work around. Posted here for others that may find this question and want to see the suggestion.

Make a copy of the file and then modify it for viewing in NotePad++. In this case `\r` is replaced with `<was CR>`.

This works because the parser looks at the original file and I look at the modified file with NotePad++.

[image]

The reason I would not consider this an acceptable answer is because I am looking for a change to a setting in NotePad++, a plug-in or some other means that is easy to do. Making copies of many files and modifying them is not something I want to do regularly.

Comment: That sounds tricky. But since you would just use it for displaying purposes, perhaps you could replace all CR characters by some other thing like unicode `NEL`, or some dummy string like `<WAS_A_CR>`

Comment: Thanks! I'm adding it as an answer because you can make the whole process automatic with macros. So you just need a single click.

Answer (score 1):

This is workaround, but I think It may work for you.

The general idea is creating a copy of the file and replace the `\r` by some dummy text like `<was CR>`

You can make the whole process automatic with macros. We will first record the action and then we will be able to 'play' them when needed. So with a single click you can have the desired effect.

1. Press record macro button
2. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> for selecting all content
3. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd> for copying the content
4. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>N</kbd> for creating a new tab
5. Paste the copied content to the new tab with <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>V</kbd>
6. Press <kbd>Control</kbd> + <kbd>H</kbd> to launch search & replace
7. Replace `\r` by `<was CR>`
8. Close search & replace dialog
9. Press top recording macro button

Now, simply press the play button on the file you want to change. Since a 'new' in-memory temporal file is created, you will not be modifying the original file.

Remember that you can save your macros so that they can persis across session restarts.

A demo of the process:

[image: Demo of the macro]

Comment: That's cool, but as you note it is a work around so no accept vote.

Comment: I think this is the closest we could get to a 'setting'... Let's see! :)

Comment: The reason I am so focused on the line endings is that when I write the rough copy of the parser I parse out just the lines and then count them. Then to verify if the rough parser is working I check the count it makes against the editor count and if they agree I keep working. In this case the  numbers were off which lead me to finding the use of CR by itself as new line display character.